# Nintendo Switch Pro controller not mapping buttons on PC for Fall Guys

Tags: controllers, fall-guys-ultimate-knockout

I have tried using my wired Nintendo Switch Pro controller on Fall Guys on PC, the one from the Epic Games Store

In the game settings menu, for the controller configuration, it is labelled "Wireless controller" (the menu, not the controller)

I still tried to map my buttons: clicked on an action which was unbound by default, then a popup asked me to push a button to map to the action, which I do, then, the popup disappeared, but the action is still unbount

I have tried doing the same for every action, and the same results happen

And of course, once ingame, no control is responding, can't even move, so I have to grab my keyboard and mouse very quickly

So here is the question: do I require a wireless controller in order to play the game with a gamepad or is there a way for me to play using my Switch gamepad?

Answer (score 0):

This took me a couple of hours to figure out but I just got it. Go to your settings on Steam, and set up your controller. Next, you go to Fall Guys manage game and go to controller options, you click on forced on, restart Steam, click global setting after and then you should be able to set up what buttons you want to use in the game.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for your answer, unfortunately, I did/do not own the game on steam, but on epic games. unless you are also implying that I should add the game to my non-steam games library?